# Add cubic bezier curves to Leaflet paths

Tags: javascript, leaflet, bezier

I'm using [Leaflet 1.0 beta](https://mourner.github.io/Leaflet/reference.html) as a tiled image viewer, so I don't need any fancy coordinate translations, GeoJSON, etc.

I'd like to be able to add cubic bezier lines to overlays, preferrably identical to how SVG `d` attribute works, since Leaflet seems to only support polygonal paths (straight lines). Is there a simple way to achieve this (e.g. by extending the `Polygon` class)?

I've tried directly changing the `d` attribute of the paths, but they get redrawn when the view changes.
I've also tried using [turfjs' bezier splines](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_bezier.html), but apparently there's no support for what I want, just the smoothing of a list of coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

I've created a [Leaflet plugin](https://github.com/elfalem/Leaflet.curve) to draw bézier curves. The format of the path data is similar to SVG path commands but only absolute commands are supported:

```
var path = L.curve(['M',[50.54136296522163,28.520507812500004],
                    'C',[52.214338608258224,28.564453125000004],
                        [48.45835188280866,33.57421875000001],
                        [50.680797145321655,33.83789062500001],
                    'V',[48.40003249610685],
                    'L',[47.45839225859763,31.201171875],
                        [48.40003249610685,28.564453125000004],'Z'],
                    {color:'red',fill:true}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Would you mind giving me an idea on how to make this work with [Leaflet.Editable](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Editable)? Thanks again!

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible to use those two plugins together. I do plan into looking into making them work together in the future, unless someone beats me to it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> You can use turf-bezier to create an interpolated bezier line out of any LineString geometry.

[Bezier spline](http://turfjs.org/docs/#bezierSpline) @ http://turfjs.org/

Answer kindly taken from tmcw @ [In Mapbox.js, how to smooth a polyline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074956/in-mapbox-js-how-to-smooth-a-polyline)

Comment: I apologize for not having included this information earlier, but I need support for cubic bezier curves, preferrably identical to how SVG `d` works. I tried using Turf before, but I couldn't understand if I can make this work and how. Could you give me a short example? Thanks!

Comment: @Whatbithever that is information you should have put, and should still put, in your question: show what you've tried, and explain why that wasn't what you wanted, so people don't have to spend time on giving you an answer that you already ruled out without telling